# How to correctly call a method between activities?

Tags: android

In the `ActivityA.java`, I have `tryAgain()` method that calls the `goToGame()` method from `ActivityB.java`.

**ActivityA.java**

```
public void tryAgain(View view) {
        ActivityB activityB = new ActivityB();
        activityB.goToGame(view);
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

because in `ActivityB.goToGame()` there is the following string:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameActivity.class);
```

I think that the error is due to a wrong argument of `activityB.goToGame()` or to `getApplicationContext()` of the intent.

In similar questions, the solution suggested is to use `static` but I face a lot of other issues with this solution.

**EDIT**

Consider that:

1. I cannot make `goToGame()` as `static`
2. I cannot change the argument `goToGame()` that as to remain `View`
3. I cannot make `goToGame()` return anything

Answer (score 1):

to call a method from your ActivityB with the right way, you can do something like this

add this your ActivityB

```
public static Intent goToGame(Context context) {

    //here do the things you want to

    return new Intent(context, GameActivity.class);
}
```

Wherever you want to open GameActivity over ActivityB, use this

```
startActivity(ActivityB.goToGame(this));
```

so this style is not right

```
ActivityB activityB = new ActivityB();
    activityB.goToGame(view);
```

do it like this

```
public void tryAgain(View view) {
    startActivity(ActivityB.goToGame(this));
}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for the answer but I cannot apply it. I have just edited the question with the reason.

Comment: I see I have a question to help, do you have an application class which on the top of everything

Comment: which normally declared as the name of the application in your manifest like this *android:name=".MyApplication"*